# This server's certificate chain is incomplete. Grade capped to B with openssl ,but jdk was not

Tags: java, openssl, ssl-certificate, keychain

I got "This server's certificate chain is incomplete. Grade capped to B" tip on ssl test when I use openssl,but I got full cert chain when I use jdkssl.

Is the feature of openssl or my configuration incorrect?

Following is validate the code of client.

```
SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
    X509TrustManager x509m = new X509TrustManager() {

        @Override
        public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
            System.out.println("getAcceptedIssuers......");
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType)
                throws CertificateException {
            System.out.println("checkServerTrusted......");
            //When I use jdkssl the chain'value is all of my server configured.
            //But when openssl the chain'value only one
            //Why this happened? is my server configuration incorrect or this is openssl's feature?
        }

        @Override
        public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType)
                throws CertificateException {
            System.out.println("checkClientTrusted......");

        }
    };
    context.init(null, new TrustManager[] { x509m }, new SecureRandom());
```

Comment: OpenSSL (libssl) server can serve a single cert, a full chain, anything in between, or even extra certs that aren't needed, depending on the application or its middleware and for most applications or middleware depending on their configuration(s), so yes it's your code and/or configuration. PS: you don't need a hacked trustmanager to see the server's offered cert(s), just use `keytool -printcert -sslserver host[:port]` or `openssl s_client -connect host:port [-servername host]`

Comment: you are right, it is beacause of the application,
I use the wildfly-openssl,the code of set cert is:
------------------------------------------------------
X509Certificate certificate = keyManager.getCertificateChain(alias)[0];
........
SSL.getInstance().setCertificate(ctx, certificate.getEncoded().....);
------------------------------------------------------
I dont know if this mean it only set the one of the full chain list.
I am trying to contact the author of wildfly-openssl.

Comment: Change the software version from 1.0.4.Final to 1.0.6.Final is ok, from 1.0.6.Final  there is no "artifactId:wildfly-openssl" but have "artifactId:wildfly-openssl-java&wildfly-openssl-linux-x86_64",thank you!